# getVersion in SAP BI 4.1 web-service C# .Net Implementation

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, business-objects

I am writing a C# code to connect to QAAWS web-service of SAP BI 4.1. Below is the code for same:

```
    BO_Session.EnterpriseCredential objCredential = new BO_Session.EnterpriseCredential();

    objCredential.Login = txtUser.Text;
    objCredential.Password = TxtPassword.Text;
    objCredential.Domain = "server:6400";
    objCredential.AuthType = "secEnterprise";

    BO_Session.Session objSession = new BO_Session.Session();
    BO_Session.SessionInfo objSessionInfo = objSession.login(objCredential,objSession.getVersion([sessionId]));
```

I need to pass sessionId value to getVersion function in the last line of code. Please help in understanding what value should I pass here.

The Web-service resides in SAP BI 4.1 environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way which worked. I had added the Web Reference to use the web-service api where-in Session Id needs to be passed as a parameter.

But then I added the dll files as a reference to the project from below mentioned path (where Business Objects Client tools are installed), the code no more needs to pass Session Id as a parameter and thus, the code does not throw any error.

> [InstallDirectory]\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\web services\dsws_consumer